# Close reason is selected randomly

Tags: support, vote-to-close, on-hold

I just closed [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12250/a-better-solution-to-switches-puzzle) on CodeGolf.

There were 2 reasons each had 2 votes on it. I chose the 2nd one (don't remember what it was because I decided not to use the "objective winning criteria missing"). I noticed that the minority (the objective winning criteria reason) was chosen to display, while the reason for the other 3 votes was not displayed.

I think this is a bug.

Comment: Did you vote to close as duplicate or for migration?

Comment: Neither of them are appropiate, no. I think it was a generic off-topic reason, maybe even a custom reason.

Comment: The other close reason was the custom off-topic close reason, and that is never shown after the question is closed except in a comment. You can see it in Peter Taylor's comment.

Comment: Well, good enough. This question lacks an objective winning critera, yes, but it is a small part of the storry.

Comment: The question is, did manatwork choose to close using Peter Taylor's custom reason? Or did he pick something else?

Comment: When I should select a close reason, there were 2 options that had 2 votes on them each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All five reasons were the same kind, "off-topic" and that's indeed what was selected.

If there were two votes for "off-topic" and two for "unclear what you're asking" and you would have chosen "unclear what you're asking" too, then that would have been the displayed on-hold reason.

As for the message displayed interjay [correctly says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192252/close-reason-is-selected-randomly#comment599774_192252) that only one of the generic reasons can be displayed there while any custom reason given will be visible as comment on the question itself.

So no bug here, not sure if the part about displaying generic reasons only is documented anywhere so if anybody find link to official statement it would be nice and until then... this can be used.